# Set Compare using SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Looking at a old OReilly book [Transact SQL Cookbook](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/network/2002/04/08/compsets.html), where a section describes in raw SQL how to perform set comparasion.

```
CREATE TABLE branch_book_list (
   branch_name CHAR(10),
   book_ISBN CHAR (13),
   book_name CHAR(40),
   PRIMARY KEY (branch_name, book_ISBN)
```

Table:

```
branch_name book_ISBN     book_name                                
----------- ------------- ---------------------------------------- 
Branch A    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming                
Branch A    1-56592-578-5 Oracle SQL*Plus: The Definitive Guide   
Branch A    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook   

Branch B    1-56592-401-0 Transact-SQL Programming                
Branch B    1-56592-756-7 Transact-SQL Cookbook                   
Branch B    1-56592-948-9 Oracle SQL*Loader: The Definitive Guide
```

Finding Rows not in the Other Set
Let's begin by writing a query to find all books held by Branch A that are not also held by Branch B. Using SQL Server, we can achieve this goal through the use of a subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT bbl1.*
FROM branch_book_list bbl1
WHERE branch_name = 'Branch A'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT bbl2.*
      FROM branch_book_list bbl2
      WHERE branch_name = 'Branch B' 
        AND bbl1.book_ISBN = bbl2.book_ISBN 
        AND bbl1.book_name = bbl2.book_name)
```

Output:

```
branch_name book_ISBN     book_name                                
----------- ------------- ---------------------------------------- 
Branch A    1-56592-578-5 Oracle SQL*Plus: The Definitive Guide
```

Now the question is,

*How should a corresponding query in SQLAlchemy using the ORM framework be?*

Answer (score 0):

Your model will be like that:

```
class BranchBookList(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'branch_book_list'

    branch_name = Column(Unicode)
    book_ISBN = Column(Unicode)
    book_name = Column(Unicode)

    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint(branch_name, book_ISBN),)
```

Into the module with the model you should define [`Session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#creating-a-session) and [`Base`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping) at first. And then there is the query with the same result as suggested:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm.util import aliased, and_
>>> from module_with_bbl import BranchBookList, Session
>>> bbl1 = Session.query(BranchBookList).filter(BranchBookList.branch_name == 'Branch A').subquery()
>>> bbl2 = Session.query(BranchBookList).filter(BranchBookList.branch_name == 'Branch B').subquery()
>>> query = Session.query(bbl1).outerjoin(bbl2, and_(bbl1.c.book_name == bbl2.c.book_name, bbl1.c.book_ISBN == >>> bbl2.c.book_ISBN)).filter(bbl2.c.book_ISBN == None)
>>> print(query)
SELECT anon_1.branch_name AS anon_1_branch_name, anon_1."book_ISBN" AS "anon_1_book_ISBN", anon_1.book_name AS anon_1_book_name 
FROM (SELECT branch_book_list.branch_name AS branch_name, branch_book_list."book_ISBN" AS "book_ISBN", branch_book_list.book_name AS book_name 
FROM branch_book_list 
WHERE branch_book_list.branch_name = :branch_name_1) AS anon_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT branch_book_list.branch_name AS branch_name, branch_book_list."book_ISBN" AS "book_ISBN", branch_book_list.book_name AS book_name 
FROM branch_book_list 
WHERE branch_book_list.branch_name = :branch_name_2) AS anon_2 ON anon_1.book_name = anon_2.book_name AND anon_1."book_ISBN" = anon_2."book_ISBN" 
WHERE anon_2."book_ISBN" IS NULL
>>> query.all()
[(u'Branch A', u'1-56592-578-5', u'Oracle SQL*Loader: The Definitive Guide')]
```

I am sure almost 100% that my version is some better, because subquery in suggested query will execute for every row in `branch_book_table`. So, if you have thousand rows in the table, there are thousand extra subqueries, while my query has only two queries.

Sorry for my English :)